# How do I force restkit to parse an array as either NSNumbers or NSStrings?

Tags: restkit

My app is parsing server side data using RESTKit.  For the most part, everything 'just works' fine, RESTKit is more than capable of recognizing that even if data is provided as a number, it should be converted to a string when assigned as a property (or vice versa in certain places).

Unfortunately, it isn't doing so inside arrays, and while it's easy enough to just make certain the server always reliably emits certain data types, I want to try and handle it inside the app as well.  ("Be conservative in what you emit, permissive in what you accept" and all that.)

The problem on my end is that I've just mapped to an array:

```
[mapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{
                                              //Other items  ommitted
                                              @"arrayKey":@"arrayKey",
                                              }];
```

The actual property is defined as :

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *palletTags;
```

Is there any way to provide restkit a type hint that it should always use strings (or NSNumbers, or whatever else I come up with) here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. If you ask RestKit to map to an array and what is received is an array then no conversion is attempted, it's just a direct assignment.

An option is to use [KVC validation](https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/wiki/Object-mapping#key-value-validation) as that allows you to verify the incoming data and, if required, mutate it before it will actually be set.

Comment: Thanks Wain... don't think it would have ever occurred to me to try and 'back door' in through validation.